# Variables in .bash_profie not reflecting in node process.env even after sourcing and machine restart

Tags: node.js, bash, terminal, gruntjs

I have following variables in my .bash_profile which i am able to see on mac terminal using echo command, however am not able to see these variables in node process.env (Except $PATH variable) while logging the same. I am running "sudo grunt taskName" to start my grunt build task and am trying to access process.env in gruntfile.js. I can only see the $PATH variable and few root user information. Any leads will be helpful.

```
export MVN_HOME=/Users/myuser/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.9
export ANT_HOME=/Users/myuser/Documents/apache-ant-1.10.3
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/
CATALINA_HOME=/Users/myuser/Documents/apache-tomcat-8.0.52
export CATALINA_HOME
export NODE_ENV=dev
export PATH=$PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$MVN_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: Why are you using sudo? Even if sudo were to start bash, since that bash would be running as root, it is root's profile it would execute.

Comment: @rici:Where should i add this variables so that i can run grunt using sudo and access it. I need run it as sudo to give write permission to grunt to certain folders and i don't want to change the default permission of those folders.

Comment: @rici: Just read that i can use .bashrc or .profile file to do so. What would you recommend among these two ?

Comment: `.profile` is shared between Bash and `sh`, so more general. `.bashrc` should only have settings which are specific to Bash.  But you can't use Bash-only syntax in `.profile` so you should fix those then.

Comment: If you want environment variables to get passed through sudo, use `sudo -E grunt`. `sudo grunt` does not start a shell, so you're barking up the wrong tree. If you don't soecify `-E`, `sudo` cleans up the environment for safety. Really, you should organize your files so that you can build projects without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Put these settings in a separate file so you can access it from your various scripts.

I would also recommend refactoring the script so it is valid `sh` script.  In particular, putting `export` on assignments is not portable.  So something like this would go in, say, `$HOME/bin/nodestuff`:

```
MVN_HOME=/Users/myuser/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.9
ANT_HOME=/Users/myuser/Documents/apache-ant-1.10.3
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/
CATALINA_HOME=/Users/myuser/Documents/apache-tomcat-8.0.52
NODE_ENV=dev
export MVN_HOME ANT_HOME CATALINA_HOME NODE_ENV
PATH=$PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$MVN_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
# no need to export PATH, your shell already does that
```

In your `.profile` you might put

```
. $HOME/bin/nodestuff
```

and in your `sudo` command line

```
sudo -s <<<". $HOME/bin/nodestuff; grunt taskName"
```

Comment: Putting your development stuff in `Documents` is just plain weird.

Comment: i am keeping it in Documents because there is an automatic backup of this folder everyday but it doesn't happens for other locations.